# Horizontal Barplot from dataframe in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

i have a dataframe named mydata with a column called "Tm" with names of teams and 10 others with statistical informations.One of them (PTS) has the points of each player. I use this code to create a new dataframe with the points of every team based on the players and the mean of points

Comment: Please provide some example data that can be copy/pasted; _e.g._ the output of `dput(mydata)` or a subset of `mydata`.

Comment: @neilfws i edit it, is that more helpful?

Comment: Yes, that's good. But from the description of the data, it sounds like the `tapply` step is unnecessary _i.e._ you could just work with `mydata` directly. And it's best not to use function names _e.g._ `mean` as variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your data frame `mydata` looks like this:

```
mydata <- data.frame(Tm = c("ATL",  "BOS",  "BRK",  "CHI",  "CHO",  "CLE",  "DAL",  "DEN",  
                            "DET",  "GSW",  "HOU",  "IND",  "LAC",  "LAL",  "MEM",  "MIA", 
                            "MIL",  "MIN",  "NOP",  "NYK",  "OKC",  "ORL",  "PHI",  "PHO",  
                            "POR",  "SAC",  "SAS",  "TOR",  "UTA",  "WAS"), 
                     PTS = c(8433, 8669, 7503, 8335, 8479, 8554, 8388, 8355, 8361, 9421, 
                             8737, 7860, 8569, 7982, 8126, 8204, 8122, 8398, 8423, 8065, 
                             9038, 8369, 7142, 8271, 8622, 8740, 7936, 8394, 8010, 8534), 
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would use `ggplot` for the bar plot. And I would not generate an additional column for the mean; just use the line to indicate its value.

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(reorder(Tm, PTS), PTS)) + 
  geom_col(fill = "grey70") + coord_flip() + 
  labs(x = "Team", y = "PTS") + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(PTS)), color = "red")
```

Another option: fill the bars according to whether their value falls above or below the mean.

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(reorder(Tm, PTS), PTS)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = PTS > mean(PTS))) + coord_flip() + 
  labs(x = "Team", y = "PTS") + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(PTS)), color = "red") + 
  guides(fill = FALSE)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: the first one work pretty good, just to problems, first i must entry in the bar the column of mean so, if you can edit the first code i would be thrilled and  when i run it the red line of mean goes in the begging and not in th end as it sound, do you know why?

Comment: Best not to put questions in answers :) someone will probably remove that. But I see in that image that the bars are not ordered, so you cannot have used the code I provided.

Comment: i fix it, thank you so much, it worked perfect i already delete it.!!!!!!

Comment: Great! Regarding the mean bar: in my opinion, the line and the bar coloring effectively provide this information (position of the mean). Adding an extra bar is not best visualization practice since it implies a category (team) which does not exist. But if you must, study the code in the other answer provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to make this type of plot, using the `diamonds` example dataset in R:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

bind_rows(diamonds %>%
              group_by(color) %>%
              summarise(price = mean(price)) %>%
              mutate(average = FALSE),
          data_frame(color = "mean", 
                     price = mean(diamonds$price),
                     average = TRUE)) %>%
    arrange(desc(price)) %>%
    mutate(color = reorder(color, price)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(color, price, fill = average)) +
    geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray80", "red")) +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this, i will try to use it, but i'm looking for something more simple, not so complicated